# Same route, different page for authenticated user or not

Tags: laravel

I want to display either `welcome.blade.php` or `login.blade.php` with the same base url `/` (because the login is in the main page)

Is this a good convention to check it in the `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/'), function () {
    if (auth()->check()) {
        // return the welcome.blade.php view
    } else {
        // return the login.blade.php view
    }
}
```

Or I should do this in a different place?

Comment: It's better to put the condition in the controller, if you have one

Comment: So in this case, I should do it in the `LoginController`

Comment: That seems a good use case of `middlewares`, `Laravel` provides an `auth` middleware out of the box.

Comment: Route "/" is for home page, I think, so you have to make a HomeController... LoginController will take care of all the login/logout logics

Comment: @Ratto thanks, will do it. 
@ths - I do use the `auth` middleware, but in this case - how to make this middleware to redirect to different pages on same URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separation of concern ! It means that whatever the module/method you write should be pure from side effects and has only one job.

`web.php` in `routes` directory serves all the routes file. So if you try to put the business logic here, it will still work but it will violate the standard of framework. All business logic either should go to `controllers` , `helpers` and all the authentication related stuff should go to `middlewares`.  Therefor, we should handle this logic inside the `controllers` if it is specific to `single` route. In our case `/`. Otherwise if we have to handle generic authentication stuff, we should go into middleware.

Therefor, the flow would look something like this

- User hit the route `/`
- Through the `web.php`, it redirected to particular `controller` let say `HomeController`.
- Inside the `HomeController` , you will put the same condition and render the `view` accordingly. i.e

```
if (auth()->check()) {
        // return the welcome.blade.php view
    } else {
        // return the login.blade.php view
}
```

We can achieve the same thing in `web.php` but it will not be according to the framework standard. Further, If you have to do more stuff other than just rendering `view`, it will get more complicated in `web.php`.

I hope it will answer your question.

Thanks,